# How to send POST request in Python (Python REST API)?

Tags: python, post, rest

I want to send POST request to VNF to save Services .

Here is my code .

```
class APIClient:

    def __init__(self, api_type, auth=None):
      
        if api_type == 'EXTERNAL':
            self.auth_client = auth

    
    def api_call(self, http_verb, base_url, api_endpoint, headers=None, request_body=None, params=None):
       
        if headers is not None:
            headers = merge_dicts(headers, auth_header)
        else:
            headers = auth_header
        url_endpoint = base_url + api_endpoint

        request_body = json.dumps(request_body)
        if http_verb == 'POST':
            api_resp = requests.post(url_endpoint, data=request_body, headers=headers)
            return api_resp
        else:
            return False
```

```
def add_service():
    for service in service_list:
        
        dict = service.view_service()
        auth_dict = {
            'server_url': 'https://authserver.nisha.com/auth/',
            'client_id': 'vnf_api',
            'realm_name': 'nisha,
            'client_secret_key': 'abcd12345',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'

        }

        api_client = APIClient(api_type='EXTERNAL', auth=auth_dict)

        response = api_client.api_call(http_verb='POST',
                                       base_url='http://0.0.0.0:5054',
                                       api_endpoint='/vnf/service-management/v1/services',
                                       request_body=f'{dict}')

        print(response)
        if response.ok:
            print("success")
        else:
            print("no")
```

When I run this code it prints

```
<Response [415]>
no
```

All the functions in VNF side are working without issues and I have no issue with GET services api call.
How to fix this ?

Comment: A `415` HTTP response code indicates an `Unsupported Media Type`. My Guess is that it has to do with your request headers. What does `auth_header` look like? Is it the same as `auth_dict`?

Comment: The `data` kwarg makes the content type form encoded, not as json. Did you mean to use the `json` kwarg in requests.post?

Comment: @C.Nivs Good catch

Comment: @PaulM.yes . Its a dictionary .

Comment: @C.Nivs . I didn't get you.  Actually I am new to python. I want to POST the services in service list to vnf. Here service_list is a list of dictionaries contain services.

Comment: what content type is the endpoint expecting? I'm assuming json

Comment: @C.Nivs . Yes . Its json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to post `application/json` data to an endpoint, you need to use the `json` kwarg in `requests.post` rather than the `data` kwarg.

To show the difference between the `json` and `data` kwargs in `requests.post`:

```py
import requests
from requests import Request

# This is form-encoded
r = Request('POST', 'https://myurl.com', headers={'hello': 'world'}, data={'some': 'data'})
x = r.prepare()
x.headers
# note the content-type here
{'hello': 'world', 'Content-Length': '9', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

# This is json content
r = Request('POST', 'https://myurl.com', headers={'hello': 'world'}, json={'some': 'data'})
x = r.prepare()
x.headers
{'hello': 'world', 'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

So you don't need the `json.dumps` step here at all:

```py
        url_endpoint = base_url + api_endpoint

        if http_verb == 'POST':
            api_resp = requests.post(url_endpoint, json=request_body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using add_service() function , without changing  APIClient class ?

Comment: You need to change the `add_service()` function or this won't work

Comment: @Nisha sorry, my mistake, you'll need to change the class because the call to `requests` is wrong

Comment: After change API class , I got this issue ,

```
http://0.0.0.0:5054/vnf/service-management/v1/services validation error: "{'auto_recover': 0, 'description': 'description31', 'service': 'apache_server21', 'service_resources': [{'name': 'apache_script1', 'type': 'script', 'config': {'file': '/etc/init.d/apache_httpd', 'user_account': ''}}], 'snmp_messages': {'error_snmp': 'error_snmp1', 'start_snmp': 'start_snmp', 'stop_snmp': 'stop_snmp'}, 'service_id': UUID('8fe1e5bf-9150-442d-ad6d-7d16f942ecef')}" is not of type 'object'

```

Comment: @Nisha this would be a different question on SO

Comment: I fixed it . Actually request_body=f'{dict}' is my mistake. So I edit it as request_body=dict.